# Why I'm getting 'return' expression required in a function with a block body error in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
open class Test1 {
    fun name(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) return (a * b)
        if (a % 2 == 1 && b % 2 == 1) return (a + b)
        if ((a % 2 == 0).xor(b % 2 == 0)) return if (a > b) (a - b) else (b - a)

    }
}

class Test2 : Test1() {

}
val obj1 = Test2()
print(obj1.name(7 , 8))
```

I'm trying to learn inheritance in Kotlin, but when I call `name` function from father class and try to print the result I get error below.
`error: a return expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first and the second condition is false, the third one must be true so you can remove the last condition. The compiler does not seem to be able to draw this conclusion, so it suspects a case where there is no return.

```
fun name(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) return (a * b)
    if (a % 2 == 1 && b % 2 == 1) return (a + b)
    return if (a > b) (a - b) else (b - a)
}
```

You can also simplify this method as follows

```
fun name(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    if (a % 2 != b % 2) return if (a > b) (a - b) else (b - a);
    return if (a % 2 == 0) (a * b) else (a + b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line of the function

```
if ((a % 2 == 0).xor(b % 2 == 0)) return if (a > b) (a - b) else (b - a)
```

if you add brackets for clarity, it would look like:

```
if ((a % 2 == 0).xor(b % 2 == 0)) {
    return if (a > b) (a - b) else (b - a)
}
```

So if the if test is false, the code won't run, which means you've reached the end of the function and still haven't returned something. You have to return an Int.

Comment: If you think it through, you'll see, that one of the three conditions is always true. Either both numbers are even, or both are odd, or (last condition) one is even and one is odd. But also the compiler doesn't seem to be able to draw that conclusion ...

Comment: Yes, no way the compiler is going to work all that out. This code block could be lifted out of the if.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, in order for your code to compile your `function` must `return` an `int` from all execution paths, your `function` doesn't satisfy that condition. ***what happens if all the `if` conditions eveluate to false?***

And second thing is that in kotlin `return` is an expression, so you can lift it out like so

```
fun name(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
   return if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0)     { (a * b) }
   else if   (a % 2 == 1 && b % 2 == 1)     { (a + b) }
   else if   ((a % 2 == 0).xor(b % 2 == 0)) { if (a > b) (a - b) else (b - a) }
   else SOME_DEFAULT_INT
}
```

Comment: If you think it through, you'll see, that one of these conditions is always true. Either both numbers are even, or both are odd, or (last condition) one is even and one is odd. But also the compiler doesn't seem to be able to draw that conclusion ...

Comment: Compiler doesn't care (Neither did I) if some of your expressions are always true, if you declare a function with a return type, then it should return a value of required type.

Comment: And as to why compiler cant draw that conclusion is because its not allowed to do so. it can only evalute constant expression, not the expressions containing a variable.

Comment: But the compiler does some codeanalysis, and when it finds all possible pathes return a value it won't complain ... It's not possible in this case (and it's not a problem that the compiler isn't able to do that). But a programmer should be able to do it.

Comment: That is what I said in my answer

Comment: Yeah, but you can replace the last `else if (...)` with just an `else` and get rid of the `else SOME_DEFAULT_INT` entirey, because that branch will never be hit. Even if the compiler isn't able to conclude that (which is totally out of scope for the compiler) the programmer should be ...